# ArgumentOutOfRangeException during Build with Tools 12.0

Tags: msbuild, tfs-2015, msbuildextensionpack

We have an (old) build definition is using the `UpgradeTemplate.xaml` on TFS 2015 (and an underlying `TFSBuild.proj` which has a heap of custom actions). As such, the task of properly modernising the build is going to take time.

I'd like to hack the UpgradeTemplate to add in C#6/VB14 support without requiring a full re-write of the build definition, in order to keep the devs happy.

I attempted to edit the UpgradeTemplate.xaml to add a ToolPath property on the TfsBuild. However, now that I have done this, I get the following error on nearly all my projects:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

On investigation, the lines of code in these projects all look like this:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.TfsVersion TaskAction="GetVersion" 
    BuildName="$(BuildDefinition)" TfsBuildNumber="$(BuildNumber)" 
    VersionFormat="DateTime" DateFormat="MMdd" Major="$(MajorVersion)" 
    Minor="$(MinorVersion)">
```

The values of these variables as set printed out by `Message` tasks on the vbproj:

> BuildDefinition: MyBuild-Testing
>   BuildNumber: 57902
>   MajorVersion: 43
>   MinorVersion: 2

The Build server has version 3.5.10 on the MSBuild ExtensionPack installed.

How do I resolve this issue? I'm testing this with a new build definition to allow devs to continue working while I get this set up, so I don't want to replace the ExtensionPack with the latest release (if possible) if it is likely to break the existing build.

**Upgrade Template**

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sad" x:Class="TfsBuild.Process" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mtbc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client" xmlns:mtbw="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mtbwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mtbwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Tracking;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:mtvc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sad="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:sad1="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:this="clr-namespace:TfsBuild;" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="ConfigurationFolderPath" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="AgentSettings" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:AgentSettings)" />
    <x:Property Name="MSBuildArguments" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="MSBuildPlatform" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:ToolPlatform)" />
    <x:Property Name="DoNotDownloadBuildType" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <x:Property Name="LogFilePerProject" Type="InArgument(x:Boolean)" />
    <x:Property Name="SourcesSubdirectory" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="BinariesSubdirectory" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="TestResultsSubdirectory" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="RecursionType" Type="InArgument(mtvc:RecursionType)" />
    <x:Property Name="Verbosity" Type="InArgument(mtbw:BuildVerbosity)" />
    <x:Property Name="Metadata" Type="mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadataCollection" />
    <x:Property Name="SupportedReasons" Type="mtbc:BuildReason" />
  </x:Members>
  <this:Process.ConfigurationFolderPath>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" />
  </this:Process.ConfigurationFolderPath>
  <this:Process.AgentSettings>[New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.AgentSettings() With {.MaxWaitTime = New System.TimeSpan(4, 0, 0), .MaxExecutionTime = New System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), .TagComparison = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TagComparison.MatchExactly }]</this:Process.AgentSettings>
  <this:Process.MSBuildArguments>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" />
  </this:Process.MSBuildArguments>
  <this:Process.MSBuildPlatform>[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.ToolPlatform.Auto]</this:Process.MSBuildPlatform>
  <this:Process.DoNotDownloadBuildType>[False]</this:Process.DoNotDownloadBuildType>
  <this:Process.LogFilePerProject>[False]</this:Process.LogFilePerProject>
  <this:Process.SourcesSubdirectory>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" />
  </this:Process.SourcesSubdirectory>
  <this:Process.BinariesSubdirectory>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" />
  </this:Process.BinariesSubdirectory>
  <this:Process.TestResultsSubdirectory>
    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" />
  </this:Process.TestResultsSubdirectory>
  <this:Process.RecursionType>[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType.OneLevel]</this:Process.RecursionType>
  <this:Process.Verbosity>[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildVerbosity.Normal]</this:Process.Verbosity>
  <this:Process.Metadata>
    <mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadataCollection />
  </this:Process.Metadata>
  <this:Process.SupportedReasons>All</this:Process.SupportedReasons>
  <mva:VisualBasic.Settings>Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces</mva:VisualBasic.Settings>
  <Sequence mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="None">
    <Sequence.Variables>
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="mtbc:IBuildDetail" Name="BuildDetail" />
    </Sequence.Variables>
    <mtbwa:GetBuildDetail DisplayName="Get the Build" Result="[BuildDetail]" />
    <mtbwa:InvokeForReason DisplayName="Update Build Number for Triggered Builds" Reason="Triggered">
      <mtbwa:UpdateBuildNumber BuildNumberFormat="[&quot;$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)&quot;]" DisplayName="Update Build Number" />
    </mtbwa:InvokeForReason>
    <mtbwa:AgentScope DisplayName="Run On Agent" MaxExecutionTime="[AgentSettings.MaxExecutionTime]" MaxWaitTime="[AgentSettings.MaxWaitTime]" ReservationSpec="[AgentSettings.GetAgentReservationSpec()]">
      <mtbwa:AgentScope.Variables>
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="buildDirectory" />
      </mtbwa:AgentScope.Variables>
      <mtbwa:GetBuildDirectory DisplayName="Get the Build Directory" Result="[buildDirectory]" />
      <If Condition="[Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationFolderPath)]" DisplayName="If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationFolderPath)">
        <If.Then>
          <mtbwa:TfsBuild BinariesSubdirectory="[BinariesSubdirectory]" BuildDirectory="[buildDirectory]" CommandLineArguments="[MSBuildArguments]" ConfigurationFolderPath="[ConfigurationFolderPath]" DisplayName="Run TfsBuild for Configuration Folder" DoNotDownloadBuildType="[DoNotDownloadBuildType]" LogFilePerProject="[LogFilePerProject]" RecursionType="[RecursionType]" SourcesSubdirectory="[SourcesSubdirectory]" TestResultsSubdirectory="[TestResultsSubdirectory]" ToolPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\" ToolPlatform="[MSBuildPlatform]" Verbosity="[Verbosity]" />
        </If.Then>
      </If>
      <If Condition="[BuildDetail.CompilationStatus = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Unknown]" DisplayName="If CompilationStatus = Unknown">
        <If.Then>
           <mtbwa:SetBuildProperties CompilationStatus="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Succeeded]" DisplayName="Set CompilationStatus to Succeeded" PropertiesToSet="CompilationStatus" />
        </If.Then>
      </If>
      <If Condition="[BuildDetail.TestStatus = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Unknown]" DisplayName="If TestStatus = Unknown">
        <If.Then>
          <mtbwa:SetBuildProperties DisplayName="Set TestStatus to Succeeded" PropertiesToSet="TestStatus" TestStatus="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Succeeded]" />
        </If.Then>
      </If>
    </mtbwa:AgentScope>
    <mtbwa:InvokeForReason Reason="CheckInShelveset">
      <mtbwa:CheckInGatedChanges DisplayName="Check In Gated Changes" />
    </mtbwa:InvokeForReason>
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

In Particular, I added `ToolPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\"` to line 58.

**TFSBuild.proj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="DesktopBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\SDC\Microsoft.Sdc.Common.tasks" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>

  <ProjectExtensions>
    <!-- Team Foundation Build Version - DO NOT CHANGE -->
    <ProjectFileVersion>2</ProjectFileVersion>
  </ProjectExtensions>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>Never</RunCodeAnalysis>
    <UpdateAssociatedWorkItems>false</UpdateAssociatedWorkItems>
    <AdditionalVCOverrides></AdditionalVCOverrides>
    <CustomPropertiesForClean></CustomPropertiesForClean>
    <CustomPropertiesForBuild></CustomPropertiesForBuild>
    <SkipGetChangesetsAndUpdateWorkItems>False</SkipGetChangesetsAndUpdateWorkItems>
    <SkipWorkItemCreation>true</SkipWorkItemCreation>
    <BuildConfigurationsInParallel>true</BuildConfigurationsInParallel>
    <SkipDropBuild>false</SkipDropBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/SolutionsToBuild/Common.sln">
      <Targets></Targets>
      <Properties></Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
      <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
      <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
    </ConfigurationToBuild>
  </ItemGroup>


  <PropertyGroup>
    <SkipClean>false</SkipClean>
    <SkipInitializeWorkspace>true</SkipInitializeWorkspace>
    <ForceGet>true</ForceGet>
    <IncrementalBuild>false</IncrementalBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Update**

I think it might be something to do with running a private build (Latest + Shelveset). When I run a normal build, the `BuildNumber` variable is `MyBuild-Testing_20170328.1`. This appears to be working fine.

Comment: Could you please share the build template for me to have a test. Do you have a parameter named "length"?

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT That might be difficult. The UpgradeTemplate calls TFSBuild.proj - that is heavily customised for our internal use. Sanitising it for company would take a fair amount of work. Let me see if I can produce a simplified version with the same error. I've updated with the values in the variables. Length is not a variable we use.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT Added the xaml/proj file contents. It appears to still break even with this simplified version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to a difference between Private and Public builds. With Public Builds, the build is immediately numbered as `BuildName_DateFormat.BuildNumber`. Private builds however, are just numeric (e.g. `57902` above).

The Code in the extension does the following:

```
string buildstring = this.TfsBuildNumber.Replace(string.Concat(this.BuildName, "_"), 
                              string.Empty);
char[] chrArray = new char[] { '.' };
string[] buildParts = buildstring.Split(chrArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
DateTime t = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(buildParts[0].Substring(0, 4), 
                                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), 
                          Convert.ToInt32(buildParts[0].Substring(4, 2), 
                                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                          Convert.ToInt32(buildParts[0].Substring(6, 2), 
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Are you can see, its substringing on the build name, assuming it's been stripped down to the date component (`20170328`). Private builds aren't this long, and so fail.

This build works fine when running as a public build - basically it means that private builds on this definition are not available until an upgrade takes place.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could mark your reply as an answer, which will also helps others in the community.